# Sqlite Update with Select subquery only chosing first value

Tags: sqlite, select, subquery

I'm having a difficult time getting the UPDATE command in Sqlite to update all records with a new value it finds in another table using a subquery select statement. It incorrectly updates every column in Table1 with the first value it finds in column Table2.
When I run the select portion of the query alone it runs fine and returns all the proper values. It basically looks up the nearest value in multiples of 300000 from a lookup table called Adjustment.

code:

```
Update TEMP1
    set New_position = 
    (
        select (Temp1.Col1 + Adjustment.Offset)  as NewValue
        from Adjustment, TEMP1
        where Adjustment.LookupValue = cast(TEMP1.Col1 / 300000 as Int) * 300000 
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a [correlated subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub):

> A SELECT statement used as either a scalar subquery or as the right-hand operand of an IN, NOT IN or EXISTS expression may contain references to columns in the outer query. Such a subquery is known as a correlated subquery. A correlated subquery is reevaluated each time its result is required. An uncorrelated subquery is evaluated only once and the result reused as necessary.

But your subquery does not actually contain a reference to columns in the outer query; the `FROM Temp1` in the inner query is a new instance of the `Temp1` table, and `Temp1.Col1` refers to that. The value of `Temp1.Col1` is from some random row in `Temp1`.

Just drop the `Temp1` from the FROM clause:

```
UPDATE Temp1
SET New_position = (SELECT Temp1.Col1 + Adjustment.Offset
                    FROM Adjustment
                    WHERE LookupValue = CAST(Temp1.Col1 / 300000 AS INT) * 300000);
```

Comment: Amazing ! That did it. Thank you so much

Comment: @DaveP you should accept the answer if it has solved your problem...